# Why do I have this java.util.NoSuchElementException?

Tags: java, class, java.util.scanner, nosuchelementexception

If I call a class member using Scanner, and if I had used Scanner before in the main method, I get the NoSuchElementException error even though all the inputs are available.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

class Reminder{
    static void computeReminder(){
        Scanner S=new Scanner(System.in);
        int a,b;
        a=S.nextInt();
        b=S.nextInt();
        int reminder = a%b;
        System.out.println(reminder);
    }
}

class TestClass{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
        int T=scan.nextInt(); //Getting no.of TestCases
        for(int i=0; i<T; i++){
            Reminder.computeReminder(); //Calling Class Method to find reminder.
        }
    }
}
```

I can use "Reminder.computeReminder();" and "int T=scan.nextInt();" separately but not together.

inputs that I used:

```
5
19 5
73 4
7 3
18 4
68 2
```

IMPORTANT CONDITION: The computeReminder() method shall have no parameters, since this is the condition given by my college's online compiler.

Comment: Nice, need to remember those comparisions ;)

Comment: Have you tried using `Scanner.hasNextInt` to actually determine that the inputs are available?

Comment: You could provide the input you're trying to use so that anyone could replicate the issue.

Comment: @Antoniossss It is always good to keep this link around http://javascriptisnotjava.com/ ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try to reuse scanner instead of creating multiple ones.

```
class Reminder{
    static void computeReminder(Scanner s){
        int a,b;
        a=s.nextInt();
        b=s.nextInt();
        int reminder = a%b;
        System.out.println(reminder);
    }
}

class TestClass{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
        int T=scan.nextInt(); //Getting no.of TestCases
        for(int i=0; i<T; i++){
            Reminder.computeReminder(scan); //Calling Class Method to find reminder.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to use an online compiler as a part of my lab course, and the given condition is that computeReminder() method shall have no arguments. I will add this to the question description.

Comment: @GauthamRameshBabu just use static constant `private static final Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);` then

Comment: it gives me an "illegal start of expression" error.